# ¿Como puedo validar argumentos?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy creando un comando de un bot de discord y mi objetivo es detectar cuando un argumento de ese comando es inválido, por ej:

Tengo estos juegos disponibles: "ajedrez" y "tresenraya"

Si pongo:

`!jugar ajedrez = //se ejecuta el ajedrez`

pero si pongo un juego que no está definido, quiero que el bot me de una respuesta diciendo que el argumento introducido no es válido:

`!jugar poker` el bot responde que el argumento es invalido ya que *"poker"* no lo tengo listado

Esto es lo que llevo de código pero no me funciona, cualquier cosa que ponga de juego aunque lo tenga listado me dice que es inválido

```
const juegos = ['ajedrez', 'tresenraya']

const elegirjuego = args[0]

if(elegirjuego != juegos) return message.reply('Argumentos inválidos!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el metodo `includes` solo se cambia una parte de tu codigo y listo

```
const juegos = ['ajedrez', 'tresenraya']

const elegirjuego = args[0]

//vemos si existe y negamos la expresion 
if(!juegos .includes(elegirjuego)) return message.reply('Argumentos inválidos!')
```

Comment: Me sigue pasando lo mismo, pongo un juego que si esta listado y me dice que el argumento no es válido

Comment: Me habia equivocado en el orden de las varibales, edite la respuesta, comparala y avisame

Comment: Me sigue pasando lo mismo, pero ```if(!juegos.includes(elegirjuego)) return message.reply('Argumentos inválidos!')``` tendría que ponerlo al final del código? O al principio?

Comment: Es decir, después de que ```if (elegirjuego) === 'ajedrez' { código del argumento }```?

Comment: la constante tiene que ser lo primero que declares, luego en tu funcion para recibir el mensaje ira la constante `elegirjuego` y luego la condicion

Comment: Pues me sigue pasando lo mismo, no lo entiendo,  yo escribo !jugar ajedrez y me dice que no es valido

Comment: asegurate de que el valor de `args[0]` no contiene ningun espacio al principio o final, ya que eso bastara para que no coincida

Comment: No tiene ningun espacio

Comment: podrias poner todo el codigo completo que tienes?, junto con lo que te dije

Comment: Acabo de mirarlo de nuevo, y en ```if(!juegos .includes(elegirjuego)) return message.reply('Argumentos inválidos!')``` se me habia olvidado poner el ```!``` delante, por eso me daba todo el rato error... Muchas gracias por la ayuda! ^^